# i have some error in python, the problem is key error

Tags: python, dictionary, syntax-error

```
def get_sent_score(TFISF_scores, text_sents, doc_info):
    """
    This function prints out the summary and return the score of arch sentence in a list.

    the score of a sentence is calculated by adding the TFIDF scores of the words that make up sentence.
    """
    sentence_info=[]
    for doc in doc_info:
        """
        This loops through each document (sentence) and calculate their 'sent_score'
        """
        sent_score=0
        for i in range (0, len(TFISF_scores)):
            temp_dict = TFISF_scores[i]
            if doc ['doc_id']==temp_dict['doc_id']:
                sent_score += temp_dict['TFISF_score']
                temp={'doc_id':doc['doc_id'],
                      'sent_score':sent_score,
                      'sentence':text_sents[doc['doc_id']-1]}
                sentence_info.append(temp)
    return sentence_info
sentence_info = get_sent_score(TFISF_scores, text_sents, doc_info)
print(sentence_info)
```

> Copy comment: the error message is
>
> ```
> sent_score += temp_dict['TFISF_score'] KeyError: 'TFISF_score'
> ```

Comment: Please be more specific, by sharing the error msg.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please describe you problem, along with your input and expected output. Reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) can be a great starting point.

Comment: Key error comes when there is no specified key in a dictionary and if you try to access it. You have multiple dictionaries here. It is not easy to solve seeing the code. Please post the error.

Comment: the error message is  sent_score += temp_dict['TFISF_score']

KeyError: 'TFISF_score'

Comment: Obviously, the offending key does not exist in the corresponding dictionary. We can't tell you why it doesn't exist; that depends on all other logic in your code.

Comment: @isabelle: There is **no** key `'TFISF_score'` in `temp_dict`. Do `print(temp_dict.keys())` to see all keys.

Comment: A good thing to do would be to debug your code with a set of print functions, including e.g. printing all the dictionary keys: `print(list(temp_dict.keys()))` just before the offending line should do that.

Comment: ok thank you so much for all the responses. i have repaired it. also there's something i want to ask again. have all of you pass some float data into another function in python?